# Function to make parent function return

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function `parent`, that calls `child`, and then does other stuff inside `otherStuff`:

```
function parent() {
    child();

    otherStuff();
}
```

Is it possible to modify `child` (and leave `parent` as is) so that the `child` call forces `parent` to return right after `child` returns? Will this be possible in EcmaScript 6?

Comment: return as in *return correctly* or as a result of an error in child? If the latter, just throw an exception in child.

Comment: Without modifying the parent you're only way is going to be to throw an exception and handle it higher up as @Yoshi suggests.

Comment: Something like [**http://jsfiddle.net/yrtS2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrtS2/) maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bad way** to do this is to throw an exception in `child`, which will bubble up to `parent` and then to the original caller. This approach makes an expectation for the original caller of `parent` to catch the exception.

```
function originalCaller() {
  try {
    parent();
  }
  catch(e) {}
}

function parent() {
  child();
  otherStuff();
}

function child() {
  throw 0;
}

function otherStuff() {
  // other stuff
}
```

You want to leave `parent` as is, right?
So, the **ugly way** is to let `child` temporarily modify `otherStuff`:

```
function child() {
  _otherStuff = otherStuff;
 otherStuff = function() { otherStuff = _otherStuff; }
}
```

This way `otherStuff` does nothing *once* and then goes back to the original state. Again, not only is it totally ugly, but makes an assumption about `parent`'s structure.